# The version of python does Elastalert Need to be installed in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, elastalert

does Elastalert need python3.6 exactly or does any version of python I see in the doc of Elastalert that it requires python3.6 ...?
https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html#